# Why does std::fill use ForwardIterator, not OutputIterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

(This question has the same "question template" as [Why does std::max_element require a ForwardIterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452356/why-does-stdmax-element-require-a-forwarditerator) but the answer has to be different, because `std::fill` doesn't return an iterator into the output sequence.)

[`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) is defined to work only when the output range is given by a pair of ForwardIterators. However, the superficially similar [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) works fine with OutputIterator.

Surely the algorithm is simply

```
template<class OutIt, class T>
void fill(OutIt first, OutIt last, T value)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *first = value;
        ++first;
    }
}
```

What about this algorithm requires ForwardIterator? What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Output iterators are not comparable. The `==` and `!=` operators are not defined for output iterators.

You need a forward iterator, because it

> satisfies the requirements of an input iterator

which supports *EqualityComparable*.

With output iterators, `std::fill` cannot compare `first` with `last`:

```
while (first != last) {
```

Not supported, for output iterators.

`std::fill_n` avoids this comparison, it just uses the counter to write to the iterator, so all it needs is an output iterator.

Comment: Oho, so it's about equality-comparability. IMHO it's unfortunate that the current standard concepts tie together the idea of "equality-comparable" and the idea of "input-iterable" — I think it would be reasonable to have something like `class SentineledOstreamIterator` that was equality-comparable `o1 == o2` and assignable `*o1 = v` but you still weren't allowed to read from it `v = *o1`. But okay, with the current concept hierarchy, I get why OutputIterator isn't constrained enough.

Comment: @Quuxplusone it doesn't make sense for a general output iterator to be comparable; e.g. imagine if the output iterator is outputting to an `ofstream` attached to a terminal . What does it mean to compare two of those?

Comment: I guess it doesn't make sense to compare general `istream` iterators either, although there is the useful case of comparing against the singular iterator (which represents end-of-file or error) in order to read the remainder of the stream; whereas for output there isn't such a thing as "write until end of file"

Comment: @M.M (second comment): exactly! *Generally* input and output iterators aren't comparable, but *sometimes* they can be. For example, the semantics of `ostream_iterator::operator==` could have been similar to `istream_iterator::operator==`, namely, return `(!x.ready() && !y.ready()) || (&x == &y)` on the underlying streams. Of course this would be useful mainly for programs that want to "write the same byte until you get a disk error or filesystem full", which is probably an uncommon case. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion of "range" for `OutputIterator`. Thus you must provide a repetition count. With `ForwardIterator` you can work over a range of elements.

Those are semantically different things. `fill_n` is for adding some elements starting from a supplied iterator. `fill` is for changing a range of elements.

Take inserters (e.g. a `back_inserter`) for an example. You can insert more elements than there is in the container, so `last` doesn't even make sense.

`OutputIterator` gives you a place where you can throw in an object. `ForwardIterator` objects must exists.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator):

> The only valid use of operator* with an output iterator is on the left of an assignment: operator* may return a proxy object, which defines a member operator= (which may be a template)

This means you basically cannot read from it, which is in the contrast to the `ForwardIterator`:

> A ForwardIterator is an Iterator that can read data from the pointed-to element.

Comment: I think your edit actually took this answer from "good" to "worse". `std::fill` doesn't attempt to read from its iterator arguments; it *does* only use `*x` on the left-hand side of an assignment. So bringing in that factoid motivates my question, but it doesn't help answer it.

Comment: Would another quote to contrast that `ForwardIterator` *must* be readable to help? I know that `fill` doesn't read elements, but it doesn't matter. It is designed to work over a range of elements. I wasn't sure if you do not understand the difference betweem the Iterator types, or the technicality which makes your proposed implementation not possible. I addressed the former. The latter was explained in the other answer. Maybe this one is gonna be useful for someone else in the future.