# Multiple iterators to a complex range

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am trying to have multiple iterators to a bit more complex range (using range-v3 library) -- manually implementing a cartesian product, using `filter`, `for_each` and `yield`. However, when I tried to hold multiple iterators to such range, they share a common value. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/for_each.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data1{1,5,2,7,6};
    std::vector<int> data2{1,5,2,7,6};
    auto range =
            data1
            | ranges::v3::view::filter([](int v) { return v%2; })
            | ranges::v3::view::for_each([&data2](int v) {
                return data2 | ranges::v3::view::for_each([v](int v2) {
                    return ranges::v3::yield(std::make_pair(v,v2));
                });
            });
    auto it1 = range.begin();
    for (auto it2 = range.begin(); it2 != range.end(); ++it2) {
        std::cout << "[" << it1->first << "," << it1->second << "] [" << it2->first << "," << it2->second << "]\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the iterator `it1` to keep pointing at the beginning of the range, while the iterator `it2` goes through the whole sequence. To my surprise, `it1` is incremented as well! I get the following output:

```
[1,1] [1,1]
[1,5] [1,5]
[1,2] [1,2]
[1,7] [1,7]
[1,6] [1,6]
[5,1] [5,1]
[5,5] [5,5]
[5,2] [5,2]
[5,7] [5,7]
[5,6] [5,6]
[7,1] [7,1]
[7,5] [7,5]
[7,2] [7,2]
[7,7] [7,7]
[7,6] [7,6]
```

- Why is that?
- How can I avoid this?
- How can I keep multiple, independent iterators pointing in various locations of the range?
- [Should I implement a cartesian product in a different way? (that's my previous question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029428/how-to-create-a-cartesian-product-range-from-filtered-data)

---

While it is not reflected in the MCVE above, consider a use case where someone tries to implement something similar to `std::max_element` - trying to return an iterator to the highest-valued pair in the cross product. While looking for the highest value you need to store an iterator to the current best candidate. It cannot alter while you search, and it would be cumbersome to manage the iterators if you need a *copy* of the range (as suggested in one of the answers).

Materialising the whole cross product is not an option either, as it requires a lot of memory. After all, the whole point of using ranges with filters and other on-the-fly transformations is to avoid such materialisation.

Comment: That `range` is a proxy object primarily thought to be lazily evaluated as it is traversed. If you want to traverse the range multiple times you probably better first transfer it to a container.

Comment: @metalfox I don't mind reevaluating stuff multiple times if necessary, but materializing a cross product into a container - that will take needlessly a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is goin on here?**

The entire problem here originates in the fact that [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) requires its arguments to be [LecacyForwardIterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) while the ranges created by `ranges::v3::yield` apparently (obviously?) only provide [LecacyInputIterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator). Unfortunately, the [range-v3 docs](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1yield__fn.html) do not explicitly mention the iterator categories one can expect (at least I haven't found it being mentioned). This would indeed be a huge enhancement as all standard library algorithms do explicitly state what iterator categories they require.

In the particular case of `std::max_element` you are not the first one to stumble over this counterintuitive requirement of `ForwardIterator` rather than just `InputIterator`, see [Why does std::max_element require a ForwardIterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12452356/9883438) for example. In summary, it does make sense, though, because `std::max_element` *does not* (despite the name suggesting it) return the max element, but an iterator to the max element. Hence, it is in particular the [multipass guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) that is missing on `InputIterator` in order to make `std::max_element` work with it.

For this reason, many other standard library functions do not work with `std::max_element` either, e.g. [std::istreambuf_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) which really is a pity: you just cannot get the max element from a file with the existing standard library! You either have to load the entire file into memory first, or you have to use your own max algorithm.

The standard library is simply missing an algorithm that really returns the max element rather than an iterator pointing to the max element. Such an algorithm could work with `InputIterator`s as well. Of course, this can very easily be implemented manually, but still it would be handy to have this given by the standard library. I can only speculate why it doesn't exist. Maybe one reason is, that it would require the `value_type` to be copy constructable because `InputIterator` is not required to return references to the elements and it might be in turn counterintuitive for a max algorithm to make a copy...

---

So, now regarding your actual questions:

**Why is this?** (i.e. why does your range only return `InputIterator`s?)

Obviously, `yield` creates the values on the fly. This is by design, it's the very reason why one would want to use yield: to not have to create (and thus store) the range upfront. Hence, I do not see how yield could be implemented in a way that it fulfills the [multipass guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator), especially the second bullet is giving me headaches:

> - If a and b compare equal (a == b is contextually convertible to true) then either they are both non-dereferenceable or *a and *b are references bound to the same object

Technically, I could imagine that one could implement `yield` in a way that all iterators created from one range share a common internal storage that is filled on the fly during the first traversal. Then it would be possible for different iterators to give you the same references to underlying objects. But then `std::max_element` would silently consume `O(n²)` memory (all elements of your cartesian product). So, in my opinion it's definitely better to not do this and instead make the users materialize the range themselves, so that they are aware of it happening.

**How can I avoid this?**

Well, as already said by metalfox, you can copy your view which would result in different ranges and thus independent iterators. Still, that wouldn't make `std::max_element` work. So, given the nature of `yield` the answer to this question, unfortunately, is: you simply cannot avoid this with `yield` or any other technique that creates values on the fly.

**How can I keep multiple, independent iterators pointing in various locations of the range?**

This is related to the previous question. Basically, this question answers itself: If you want to *point* independent iterators in *various locations*, these locations have to exist somewhere in memory. So, you need to materialize at least those elements that did once have an iterator pointing to them, which in case of `std::max_element` means that you have to materialize all of them.

**Should I implement a cartesian product in a different way?**

I can imagine many different implementations. But none of them will be able to provide both of these properties all together:

- return `ForwardIterator`s
- require less than `O(n²)` memory

Technically, it could be possible to implement an iterator that is specialized for the usage with `std::max_element`, meaning that it keeps only the current max element in memory so that it can be referenced... But this would be somewhat ridiculous, wouldn't it? We cannot expect a general purpose library like range-v3 to come up with such highly specialized iterator categories.

---

**Summary**

You are saying

> After all, I don't think my use case is such a rare outlier and ranges
>   are planned to be added to the C++20 standard - so there should be
>   some reasonable way to achieve this without traps...

I definitely agree that "this is not a rare outlier"! However, that doesn't necessarily imply that "there should be some reasonable way to achieve this without traps". Consider e.g. [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problems. It is not a rare outlier to be facing one. Still, it is impossible (unless P=NP) to solve them in polynomial time. And in your case it is simply not possible to use `std::max_element` without `ForwardIterator`s. And it is not possible to implement a `ForwardIterator` (as defined by the standard library) on a cartesian product without consuming `O(n²)` memory.

For the particular case of `std::max_element` I would suggest to just implement your own version that returns the max **element** rather than an iterator pointing to it.

However, if I understand your question correctly your concern is more general and `std::max_element` is just an example. So, I have to disappoint you. Even with the existing standard library some trivial things are impossible due to incompatible iterator categories (again, `std::istreambuf_iterator` is an existing example). So, if range-v3 happens to be added, there will just be some more of such examples.

So, finally, my recommendation is to just go with your own algorithms, if possible, and swallow the pill of materializing a view otherwise.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your detailed answer. This opens my eyes onto some aspects of iterators I was not aware of. I can see now how the bullet you cited in the multipass guarantee is problematic. However, if we would replace it with something slightly weaker, the cross product could be implemented as a pair of `ForwardIterator`-s and referencing it would return an object holding two references to were each component references. I think it would work with `std::max_element` and other functions. The limiting factor seems to be the formalisation and not the general algorithmic inability to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the resulting view stores state such that it turns out to be single pass. You can work around that by simply making as many copies of the view as you need:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> data1{1,5,2,7,6};
    std::vector<int> data2{1,5,2,7,6};
    auto range =
            data1
            | ranges::v3::view::filter([](int v) { return v%2; })
            | ranges::v3::view::for_each([&data2](int v) {
                return data2 | ranges::v3::view::for_each([v](int v2) {
                    return ranges::v3::yield(std::make_pair(v,v2));
                });
            });

    auto range1= range;         // Copy the view adaptor
    auto it1 = range1.begin();

    for (auto it2 = range.begin(); it2 != range.end(); ++it2) {
        std::cout << "[" << it1->first << "," << it1->second << "] [" << it2->first << "," << it2->second << "]\n";
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
    for (; it1 != range1.end(); ++it1) { // Consume the copied view
        std::cout << "[" << it1->first << "," << it1->second << "]\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another option would be materializing the view into a container as mentioned in the comments.

---

Keeping in mind the aforementioned limitation of single-pass views, it is not really hard to implement a `max_element`
function that returns an iterator, with the important drawback of having to compute the sequence one time and a half.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
template <typename InputRange,typename BinaryPred = std::greater<>>
auto my_max_element(InputRange &range1,BinaryPred &&pred = {}) -> decltype(range1.begin()) {
    auto range2 = range1;
    auto it1 = range1.begin();
    std::ptrdiff_t pos = 0L;

    for (auto it2 = range2.begin(); it2 != range2.end(); ++it2) {
        if (pred(*it2,*it1)) {
            ranges::advance(it1,pos);   // Computing again the sequence as the iterator advances!
            pos = 0L;
            }
        ++pos;
        }
    return it1; 
}
```

Comment: Uch, it will work for my minimum working example showing the initial problem, but imagine you want to implement a `maximum` function over the range, returning `it2` to the found maximum, while iterating with `it1`. Under a certain condition (found higher value) `it2` needs to set to the current value of `it1`. Setting it to "the same element as `it1` but within the range copy" would be cumbersome to achieve I think? I could, for example, remember how far I need to advance. But at that point I am asking myself, why use this kind of ranges if they are so weird to use?!

Comment: @CygnusX1 Note that you are combining every possible combination the elements of `data1` and `data2` on the fly (lazily). That’s very powerful. `decltype(range)::iterator` becoming an *InputIterator* seems to me a reasonable price to pay. Some views downgrade the `iterator_category` of the input range. For example `view::filter` can be at most *BidirectionalRange* even when the input range provides random access. In your example you are creating temporary pairs `(v,v2)`. It is quite logical to me that `range` is single pass.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Do you really need to return an iterator? Can’t you just return the *value* it wraps?

Comment: `std::max_element` for regular container returns an iterator. I am trying to implement something similar here. Cross product seems to me as a trivial operation, and I don't really see a reason for it to be of any lesser category than the types of iterators it combines. But I am a novice range-v3 user, the above behavior - one iterator per range - seems totally counter-intuitive and unexpected. Took me a while to debug it and figure out the library tricked me leading to the question above.

Comment: @CygnusX1 I agree that caching `begin` may be counter-intuitive. I have added some rationale I found to the answer.

Comment: I don't think the caching of `begin` is a problem. As long as I don't change the values of the container, `begin()` returns the same thing and that is fine in my case as well. But when I increment an iterator, *all* iterators to this range seems to be incremented.

Comment: @CygnusX1 I've added a possible implementation of `max_element`, though I don't thing it's a sound approach.

Answer (score -1):

An iterator is a pointer to an element in the vector, in this case, it1 points to the beginning of the vector. And hence, if you are trying to point the iterator to the same location of the vector, they will be the same. However, you can have multiple iterators pointing to different locations of the vector. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: But I increment `it2` while I do not increment `it1`. Yet, `it1` still points at the same location as `it2` after multiple iterations.